# How can a graphql mutation accept an array of arguments with apollo server express?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm creating a shopping cart in my frontend, and I want to pass all the items in the shopping cart as an array to my mutation addLicense on my backend, so I don't have to make multiple API calls. Is this possible? If so, how, or what are my options?

I've tried to add square brackets around the arguments like this

```
extend type Mutation {
    addLicense([
        licenseType: String!
        licenseAmount: String!
        isActive: Boolean
        expirationDate: Date!
    ]): License!
}
```

I've also tried to set the object type as an argument

```
extend type Mutation {
    addLicense(
    license: [License]
): License!
```

First attempt throws this error

```
/app/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1463
throw (0, _error.syntaxError)(lexer.source, token.start, "Expected ".concat(kind, ", found ").concat((0, _lexer.getTokenDesc)(token)));
^
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found [
at syntaxError 
(/app/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:24:10)
```

The other attempt throws this error

```
Error: The type of Mutation.addLicense(license:) must be Input Type but got: [License].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some advices over at the GraphQL Slack. I solved it by adding a new Input Type.

```
input LicenseInput {
    id: ID
    licenseType: String!
    licenseAmount: String!
    isActive: Boolean
    expirationDate: Date
    course: String!
    organizationID: String!
    price: Int!
}
```

I was then able to add my mutation like so

```
extend type Mutation {
    addLicense(
        license: [LicenseInput] <-
    ): License!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your mutation:

```
type Mutation {
    """
    Add multiple items to basket
    """
    addLicenses(licenses: [License!]!): LicenseMutationBatchResult
}
```

your interface input:

```
input License {
    licenseType: String!
    licenseAmount: String!
    isActive: Boolean
    expirationDate: Date!
}
```

whatever you give back:

```
type LicenseMutationBatchResult {
    ...whatever you give back here...
}
```